# Stream PDF file from http response directly to client with Python requests library using client certificate

Tags: python, django, python-requests, client-certificates, pkcs#12

I'm making a request to an endpoint that returns a PDF as streamable binary. This endpoint uses mutual TLS authentication so when I hit the endpoint I must send a client certificate. To achieve this I am using https://pypi.org/project/requests-pkcs12/ which supports the Python requests library.

I would like to download this PDF from the client.
Ideally when the end user clicks 'download' it hits the endpoint and directly streams the data and downloads it.
I am struggling to do this in one single step.

Currently what I'm doing is downloading the PDF to a file, then sending this file back to the client. Writing to the file is slow and I'd like to avoid the download-to-file step and simply send a streaming response back somehow.
Is there a way to stream this directly using Python's Request?

```
 #hit the mutual tls authenticated endpoint
response = post(f'{url}, stream=True, pkcs12_filename=client_certificate_path, 
pkcs12_password=client_certificate_passphrase)

#Write the returned data to a file
    with open('/tmp/newfile.pdf', 'wb') as f:
             f.write(response.content)

#Send the file back to client with Django's FileResponse
    return FileResponse(open('/tmp/newfile.pdf', 'rb'))
```

While I am using Django which seems to handle this problem nicely with `StreamingHttpResponse`, I was unable to get this working as it doesn't allow me to send a client certificate and password protected client certificate key.